# Firebase Push Notification sent, but onMessage() not firing

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am sending a push notification from Postman.

I've got the Authorization and Content-Type headers set and my Body looks like this:

```
{
    "to" : "faecDTf47y4:APA91bEsGFDeKQtifs-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 

    "notification": {
        "title": "Hello",
        "body": "World!",
        "icon": "/images/favicon.png"
  }

}
```

When I submit the post request, I get the following JSON response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": XXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, it looks like it was sent successfully, but it seems like the notification isn't actually fired.

I'm following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/BsCBCudx58g?t=337
And so far everything is working up until I get to reading the notification with the onMessage() function.

My Service Worker looks like this:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

and my main.js looks like this:

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

navigator.serviceWorker
.register('/site/serviceworker-firebase-messaging.js', { scope: '/site/' })
.then(function(registration) {

console.log("◕◡◕ Firebase Service Worker Registered");
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
    console.log('Firebase has permission.');
    return messaging.getToken();
}).
then (function(token) {
    console.log('Firebase messaging Token', token);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Firebase has encountered an error.', err);
});

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('onMessage: ', payload);
});

});
```

I'm testing in Chrome.

**EDIT**

When I am not on the tab where my web application is, I do get a notification when I submit from Postman.  It just pops up and says **"This site has been updated in the background."**  But it doesn't have my message/title/icon.

Comment: Funny thing.... after closing the tab completely, both my issues were resolved.  My notification is displayed correctly when tab is not open and the payload is being written to the console when the tab is open.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 8):

Although the question is a bit old and the OP already answered it in a comment, I would add this answer in case it helps:

- The `onMessage` event is only triggered only when your website tab is open and selected (active) so you can handle the incoming notification the way you desire.
- But if the the tab is not active then the browser handles the incoming notification and the `onMessage` event is not triggered.

Comment: This suggestion help for the foreground message, thanks. Would like to add, for users using Chrome to debug. Do not use the same window, open 1 window with Google firebase(for the trigger), and another window with the FCM script running in foreground.

Answer (score -1):

The messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) will be triggered when the application is on background.